# Can you create a list of class objects and use class functions that way?

Tags: python, function, class, call

I am trying to create a list of class objects, so that I can access functions and properties of a class/object by refering to that list. I looks something like this:

```
class Modul:
   def __init__(self, name, dozent, time):
        self.name = name
        self.dozent = dozent
        self.time = time
        listofmodules.append(self) #i also tried what will be in the main marked with *option instead

   def __str__(self):
      return self.name + "at" + self.time "tutored by" + self.dozent

   def a_function(self):
      #do something

if '__main__':
   listofmodules = []
   name = "subject" 
   dozent = "tutor" 
   time = "2 hrs"
   new_module = Modul(name, dozent, time)
   listofmodules.append(Modul(name, dozent, time)) #*option
```

I would like to do things like:

```
to_use = input("What module would you like to use?")
listofmodules.index(to_use)
listofmodules[index].a_function
```

Is this even possible at all? If yes, why does it save the **str** in the list? How do I make it not save the string but the module instead? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'save the str in the list'?

Comment: I mean to put them all in a list so that I can access them easily in the future

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't quite make sense, because every time you create a new `Modul` you're appending `self` to `listofmodules`. This means that you'll get a growing list of objects - this is probably not the desired effect!
Using the "Bob at 15 tutored by Alice" form is not a reliable way to refer to the module - you should use id!
`list.append` can only add objects at the end of a list - use `list.index` to search for a given object.
You want to prefer casing conventions - normally you'd write `MyObject`.
`a_function` should probably just be `self.a_function` - I guess that you don't need the `self`

```
listofmodules.append(Modul(name, dozent, time))
```

This will create a new Modul, with the "Bob at 15 tutored by Alice" name, and append it to the list. This will create a new instance, however if you're trying to save the same one twice, you don't need to do anything.

```
my_modul = Modul(name, dozent, time)
listofmodules.append(my_modul)

# ...

to_use = input(What module would you like to use?)

for item in listofmodules:
  if str(item) == to_use:
    item.a_function()
    break
else:
  print("Didn't find given module!")
```

```
to_use = input(What module would you like to use?)
listofmodules.index(to_use)
listofmodules[index].a_function
```

This does not work, and will likely result in an error for `list.index`. `list.index` will search for a matching object - since you're modifying the `str` representation of the object when you're asking for it, this will not work.
Alternatively, we can add an attribute to the module:

```
class Modul:
  def __init__(self, name, dozent, time, use_for_identity=None):
        self.name = name
        self.dozent = dozent
        self.time = time
        self.use_for_identify = use_for_identity or name

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name + at + self.time tutored by + self.dozent
  def a_function(self):
    #do something
```

Now we can do:

```
my_modul = Modul(name, dozent, time, use_for_identity="cool")
listofmodules.append(my_modul)

# ...

to_use = input(What module would you like to use?)

for item in listofmodules:
  if item.use_for_identify == to_use:
    item.a_function()
    break
else:
  print("Didn't find given module!")
```

Comment: Thank you this is the best answere I ever got here :) I really understand the problem now! Thank you